# How to persist user login for long period of time in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, authentication

I have built an application with the MERN stack (Mongo, Express, React & NodeJs). Now I am doing research on building an authentication system. There are literally tons and tons of tutorials and video's where a system is built on which the user is authenticated for a maximum of let's say 24 hours and then has to re-login. They all use either `jwt` or `session` with something like `express-session`. **However**, I am using certain websites where I am basically never logged out.

I would really like to create a system myself where the user is authenticated for atleast 14 to 30 days without being prompted to re-login (ideally even longer). I cannot find good resources online on how to persist user login for long periods of time. I am aware that there are massive security trade-offs involved in creating such a system. I am also aware that I can just set the expiry time of a `jwt` or the `maxAge` of a session cookie to something like 14-30 days, but that seems like a really bad idea. However, I would really like to learn & read more about these authentication methods with persistent login over long periods of time.

Could someone provide some good resources / insights on this particular subject? What are some things that I should take into account?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, because security is difficult to implement correctly, it's recommended to use a third-party OAuth provider or at least a well-tested library for local authentication and authorization.

If you want to build your own system, you can implement a system with two tokens. An authorization token and a refresh token. Set the expiry on the auth token to something short like an hour and the refresh token for as long as you'd like.

Pass the auth token on all requests and validate it on the back end. When the auth token expires, the server sends back an invalid token message and the client should then request a new auth token passing the refresh token. The server validates the refresh token and issues a new auth and refresh token to the client. This process repeats until the refresh token expires.

If both tokens expire, then the user must re-authenticate. When a user logs out, you need to expire / delete the auth and refresh tokens on both the client and server.

This system minimizes the exposure of a captured auth token while enabling the client access over longer periods of time.

This is only a rough, and simplified version of how such a system could work. You'll have to come up with some way to validate tokens and keep track of which tokens belong to which users.

Comment: Allright, so if I understand you correctly: generate short lived auth token and long lived refresh token. Store AT (accestoken) and RT (refreshtoken) in session cookies and the RT also in the database. Send AT with every req. If expired, send RT and verify & compare with RT in the database. Then issue new AT and RT?

Comment: if you have to go for hassle of double token storage, refresh tokens, maintain a state then why got a standard cookie based session management. What additional benefits is JWT bringing to table? If force fitting JWT in design is intention then certainly you are successful here.

Comment: @indolentdeveloper It reduces the amount of exposure to captured authentication because the tokens are constantly rotated. It's a main feature of OAuth. Check out [this explanation](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/).

Comment: @Reinier68 Generally, you are correct. However, you don't want to store the tokens in the session. You want to store them in cookies with the HttpOnly and SameSite attributes set. Again, I do not recommend doing this yourself. Use an OAuth library and a provider like Google, Amzon Congnito, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For long period time sessions using stateless jwt may not be best idea.

As critical requirement would be session invalidations, token theft detection, which jwt by itself cannot provide. You need some surrounding smart components  for the whole setup.

> Stateless JWT tokens cannot be invalidated or updated, and will introduce either size issues or security issues depending on where you store them. Stateful JWT tokens are functionally the same as session cookies, but without the battle-tested and well-reviewed implementations or client support.

Unless you work on a Reddit-scale application, there's no reason to be using JWT tokens as a session mechanism. Just use sessions.

[http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)

Comment: I can use sessions and I've read some tutorials on them. They all use a maxAge on the sessions of 24 hours (or less). Obviously I can just crank the maxAge up to however long I want, but I am not sure on how 'safe' that is. Do you have any knowledge about that?